# Sharing data between python and a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html

A noob question, I know, but I wondered what the easiest way of solving this problem is:

**Background**

I have a python program running on raspberry pi that logs temperature data to a csv. It periodically renders the csv data into a graph of 'temperature over time' (a png) and posts the png to my personal slack channel.

I've added an apache2 server to the pi, and that shows a single webpage with the chart (link below).

I would like to add to the webpage, so it also says 'Temperature at [hh:mm] was [x] C' at the bottom.

I have all the time/data values in the python program, **what's a clean (easy?) way to surface these values into the webpage?**

[The webpage, as is, I'd like to add dynamic values at the bottom of the page, from a python program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRy1S.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a cool project! I like it :) You can expose your data through an API in Python and fetch it with your frontend. Have a look into these two frameworks:

1. [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)
2. [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/)

They are both nicely suited to solve your problem. There is a nice YouTube playlist by Corey Schafer, you may know him: [Flask Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH) -- Another great introduction to exposing APIs with flask is this article: [Creating Web APIs with Python and Flask](https://programminghistorian.org/en/lessons/creating-apis-with-python-and-flask)

Comment: Thank you! I've lost a lot of time reading around looking at javascript/node/flask and been finding it really hard to work out which would work/never work/be unnecessarily complex! That steer helps a lot!